# Cross entropy minimization

Tags: neural-networks, entropy

I just read about Cross-entropy cost function for my work.
and I see a notation that said "the minimization of cross entropy of some data is equal to maximization of their log likelihood."
How can I achieve this result?
How can I show that?

Comment: It would help to [edit] your question to provide additional context.  I suggest providing a full citation for where you read it, and summarizing the context.  It's not clear what you mean by "minimizing the cross entropy of some data"; if the data is fixed, there is nothing to minimize.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/364216/2921